# Qual checklist você segue antes de criar um tópico?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, comunidade

Esse tópico não tem a pretensão de achar que usuários novos vão seguir algum procedimento, conduta, tour...etc. Muito menos promover uma caça as bruxas a usuários que não seguirem x ou y procedimentos. Ele tem a intenção de colher a experiência de usuários, compartilhar essas experiências, para que exista cada vez mais tópicos de qualidade. Tudo que tem que fazer, é compartilhar uma lista de comportamentos comuns que **você** faz, antes de criar um tópico no StackOverflow. Faça crítica e sugestões ao checklist de outros. Quem sabe sintetizamos um checklist central. Vamos começar com o que eu faço antes de criar ou desistir de criar um tópico.

**1 - Reflexão sobre o problema** - A primeira que tento fazer quando tenho um problema, é refletir sobre regra de negócio. Será que eu entendi realmente o problema? É necessário eu realmente seguir este caminho para solucionar o problema? Se eu chegar a conclusão de que sei aonde quero chegar naquela tarefa, eu passo para a etapa 2.

**2 - Eu tenho alguma coisa em mente que pode resolver este problema? -** No passado, na época que eu frequentava bastante fóruns, repara que algumas das soluções eu era capaz de construir, ou até mesmo chegar naquela solução usando a imaginação. Daí pensei: Alguns problemas que temos realmente são de programação? É um problema de sintaxe? É um problema de paradigma? Ou apenas não tive imaginação/malandragem/experiência/etc para resolver esse problema? Existe um [texto na internet](http://melhorcodigo.com/boas-praticas/voce-e-mesmo-um-programador-ou-apenas-um-bom-googler/) bem humorado que fala sobre esse assunto. A resposta sendo afirmativa nessa última pergunta, passo para etapa 3.

**3 - Testes de solução -**  Nesta etapa você realmente vai tentar de forma criativa solucionar o problema. Caso não consigo, pode consultar a documentação oficial da ferramenta/linguagem que está trabalhando. Talvez seja um problema que aquela linguagem tenha uma solução nativamente. Não conseguindo, vou para etapa 4.

**4 - Pesquisa em fóruns -** Existe uma chance de sua dúvida virar um grande bla bla blá e realmente ninguém entender a questão. Caso sua isso aconteça, vá para a etapa 5.

**5 - Exemplo mínimo viável reproduzível -** Já tem tópico no stack falando deste item. Tenho que fechar a empresa agora. Não vejo problema chegar nessa etapa, desde que seja objetivo, e resumido o seu problema, descreva suas tentativas com exemplo de código, etc.

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem. A sua proposta é cada um fazer o seu e comentarmos sobre cada ou comentar sobre o seu checklist?

Comment: Todos fazerem seu cheklist, e comentar sobre. E porque não, comentar sobre o meu também. Mas principalmente a primeira opção

Comment: Meu checklist: Estou desenvolvendo algo, 1. Alguma coisa não funciona ou tem um comportamento diferente do esperado. 2. Procuro a respeito. 3. Se não achar nada, ou não achar conteúdo em português sobre, ou sentir falta de alguma explicação, pego meu código, altero o que for necessário e crio uma pergunta.